Formalities on loop invariant - algorithms
When proving an algorithm using a loop invariant, we need to check these three things.

The loop invariant holds before the loop is entered (initialization)
If the loop invariant holds before the loop is entered then the loop invariant holds before entering the next iteration of the loop (maintenance)
The loop is finite

We can then use the information we obtained from the loop invariant to continue our proof. However, is there are formal way of specifying what "BEFORE the loop is entered" means? Intuitively, it is very clear what that phrase means, but if I take the following examples:
Define variables... <--
while "condition":  
    Do something

In the code above, the phrase "BEFORE the loop is entered" means to look at how the variables are defined up to the line just above the while loop (i.e up to the line marked by the arrow, including it).
However, in the following example, when using a for loop instead:
Define variables... 
for i in "some array":  <--
    Do something

Here, the phrase "BEFORE the loop is entered" means to go and look how the variables are defined INCLUDING the "first line" of the for loop (marked by the arrow), i.e we would have all the previously defined variables AND the variable defined in the for loop line (i).
It seems to me that the while loop is much clearer when wanting to prove the correctness of an algorithm using loop invariant, since "BEFORE the loop is entered" literally means to look up to the line BEFORE we invoke the "while" loop, but in the "for" loop it takes some "extra-thinking". Hence my question to see if there are any formalities that can explain this difference.

If this question is more appropriate for another StackExchange community please let me know, but I thought that many users could add valuable insight.

In each case "before the loop" is right after you have defined the variables. (Better question for theoretical computer science SE. )

It means "before the loop body is entered". If the language has introductory red-tape (like the "for" clause) that forms part of the syntax of the loop statement but defines code that is executed before the loop body, then that should be treated as part of the initialization. And I strongly agree with @EthanBolker that your question would be more appropriate on an SE site that is more concerned with programming and program verification.

It doesn't really matter. For any loop invariant, you can put your arrow before the "Define variables ..." but add the initialized variables to the statement of the invariant as AND conditions. You can have an invariant that strictly speaking holds for all iterations starting from the third iteration (inside the loop). You can still see/construct and invariant that holds "before the loop starts" by adding the description of the states during the first 3 iterations to the statement of the invariant.
